# Rails - Use Redcarpet as Markdown interpreter, how can I make all links have a html targer _blank attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redcarpet

I use Redcarpet as my backend Markdown interpreter solution.

I want all links to have a html target attribute and its value equal to '_blank', but I can't find any solution for it.

Could any one help me?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I write JavaScript to handle it...

I think this is the fastest way....

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't know specifically how to do this, I would look at using a [custom renderer](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet#and-you-can-even-cook-your-own):

```
#app/lib/blank_targets.rb
class BlankTargets < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  def link(link, title, content)
    #custom code here
  end
end

#Your Controller
markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(BlankTargets)
```

Answer (score 2):

They've since introduced a new option, which you can use like so:

```
link_attributes: { target: '_blank' }
```